Convert SVG transform: rotate(angle, x, y) to rotation, posX and posY
I am trying to parse SVG files, and stumbled upon transform-rotate with three values: angle (in degrees), and pivot points x and y. The rotation is of course straight forward, but how do I calculate new position from the pivot points? Do I need more variables, and if so – which?

the new co-ordinate system is the old one rotated about the pivot point. It's not clear what it is that you're not understanding.

You're right – it's dead simple, I was just overthinking it. There were some additional transforms on the element I was parsing, and it threw me.
